# Create a custom keyboard layout with a personal script

Tags: linux, keyboard, fonts, keyboard-layout, unicode

I am a user of Debian Jessie at the momment.
For personal reasons I have created a script (the glyph kind, not the programming one) that I have been using in the computer as a font for years, but using it like that wastes a lot of time (time that I need to do more stuff than fighting with the text editors to do what I need).

I have been told that I could, somehow (that I wasn't told), create a keyboard layout with my script (even not being it in unicode) in the manner that I only had to switch the keyboard layout when I need to use the 'other' script.

I have been trying to modify already existing keyboard layouts associated with languages that had similar 'features' to my script, but none of them work (I know that is my ignorance related to programing what is at fault here).

I've been trying workarounds on this issue:

- Keayboardlayouteditor does not work, altogether (character map no matter what I do, doesn't open, maybe I need to install some package that I don't know is missing?).
- In IBus, modifying existing .mim files on the m17n thing results in random letters in latin being shown instead of my script's (because they are not unicode? I don't know).

So I would need some guide, book, or knowledge in order to make my script into a keyboard layout that writes from right to left, with syllabic characters kind of input, and with my already done font. Any ideas or further information on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xkbd` to create very flexible keyboard layouts. I recommend to read the [Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.600.7058) from beginning to end first, and then attempt to write some layout.

Have a look at existing keyboard layouts (`/usr/share/X11/xkb/` on Debian and probably many other distros) for syllabic languages like Japanese (Hiragana/Katakana) to get an idea how to handle mode switches between ASCII and syllabic layouts.

You also should assign some unicode codepoints in the [private use areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) to your script/font. I don't know how your font is encoded, but if you reuse the ASCII encoding or similar you will be making everything *extremely* difficult for you.

I can't stress this enough: Keep the encodings separate, and use Unicode. A script, `iconv` table or whatever that converts your old encoding to unicode is quickly written, and you'll save yourself a lot of pain.